# Python - How to embed OLE in word document using python

Tags: python

we are facing issue to embed the OLE word using python script.
Below is the example which we have tried.

```
ms_word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
ms_doc = ms_word.Documents.Add('mydoc.docx')
```

But OLE is not embedded into word.

OLE is successfully embedded in Excel using python script below

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
objsws = ws.OLEObjects()
```

Please help us, how to embed the OLE in word using python script

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly do you want ? Do you want to extract the OLE objects in the word file ?

Comment: We want to embed the OLE object in the word document. As mentioned above we are able to embed the OLE object in excel, below is the sample program.

{ import win32com.client as win32
import os 
from tkinter import messagebox
import win32clipboard

# (0) Setup
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dir_path)
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(dir_path + "\\" + "test_excel.xlsx")
ws = wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
objs = ws.OLEObjects()
 }

Comment: @Shanky Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for quite some time myself, and there are not many answers out there.  In my case, I needed to embed PDF documents within Word documents.  The caveat for me was that each word document was dynamically generated by Python using Python Docx (an awesome tool, btw!). Here's the solution I cobbled together:

```
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
docpath = "C:\\temp\\lms\\test.docx" # Path to the Word doc
doc = word.Documents.Open(docpath)
word.Visible = False

doc.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(FileName=fn, IconFileName='C:\\temp\\lms\\file_pdf.ico', 
            DisplayAsIcon=1, Range=doc.Tables(1).Cell(6,2).Range)
```

In my case:

fn = file name to embed

IconFileName = This is the icon image you want to use if you want to have an icon displayed.

DisplayAsIcon = T/F, self explanatory

Range = This one is a real bear, and MSFT documentation on range is pretty lame.
In my case, I was inserting the PDF in the 1st table within the document, cell 6,2.

You can use other methods in the Range such as paragraphs.

HTH